# How can I ensure digit-only JSON keys are interpreted as Strings, not Numbers?

Tags: javascript, json, safari

I have a JSON `String` holding IDs as keys, which are just `Strings` of numbers, and actual `Numbers` (`Float`) as values. Parsing it to obtain an object has nasty effects in Safari 10.1.2...

```js
var myStr = "{\"53352\":0.6, \"82008\":0.4}";
var myStrParsed = JSON.parse(myStr);
console.log(myStrParsed);
```

... will result in the following parsed object:

```
{
  "0": NaN,
  "1": NaN,
  "2": NaN,
  "3": NaN,
  "4": NaN,
  "5": NaN,
  "6": NaN,
  "7": NaN,
  ...
```

When I actually expect the following:

(as executed in Firefox 55.0.3)

```
 Object {53352=0.6, 82008=0.4}
```

(as executed in Safari 11.0)

```
{
  "53352": 0.6,
  "82008": 0.4
}
```

I know that the huge array obtained from Safari is due to Safari misinterpreting the `String` keys as `Number`, which generates an array with indices up to 82008. Of course, this is not intended. How can I make sure Safari correctly interprets the keys as `Strings`?

### Approaches so far

I have the liberty to make the server prepend an underscore as prefix to all keys, such as `_53352` instead of `53352`. This will fix the issue, but I'll have to strip the underscore from the key on the client. The whole approach feels hacky and inconsistent, because I do not append this underscore to IDs elsewhere. Are there other ways to ensure an interpretation as `String`?

Using [org.json](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) on the server side to encode JSON.

Comment: Are you sure the result you're expecting is correct? The example given outputs `{
  "53352": 0.6,
  "82008": 0.4
}`. Please make sure the examples given are [mcve]s.

Comment: [Bug 170442 - Safari 10.1 JSON.parse returns incorrect object for numeric keys with decimal values](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170442)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes I'm positive, how the object is put into console differs from browser to browser, but it should always represent an object with two key/value pairs. Hence, the output I declared as "expected" and the one you posted are equal.

Comment: @Andreas Has this issue been fixed in the current version of Safari?

Comment: @DoubleM this isn't occurring on Safari 11.0.

Comment: I'm not familiar with webkit but according to their [bug live cycle](https://webkit.org/bug-life-cycle/) the bug has still to be verified and publicly released

Comment: @Andreas Thank you. I have updated to Safari 11 which fixes the issue. If you add an answer saying that this is a bug in Safari 10ish and there's no need to mark a key as `String`, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known bug in Safari 10.x

[Bug 170442 - Safari 10.1 JSON.parse returns incorrect object for numeric keys with decimal values](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170442)

According to @evolutionxbox the bug seems to be fixed in v11.